# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SCNVector3' and 'Double'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, arkit

I have a need where i have to multiply SCNVector3 with 0.1 to get a new position. When i try to do this, i am getting below error. This was working before in earlier Xcode Versions. I am using Xcode 10.1 with compiler of Swift 4 version. I have seen other answers for same kind of question but the data type differs here.

```
Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SCNVector3' and 'Double'
```

And the code i am using is below,

```
   guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }

    let mat = pointOfView.transform
    let dir = SCNVector3(-1 * mat.m31, -1 * mat.m32, -1 * mat.m33)
```

> let currentPosition = pointOfView.position + (dir * 0.1)  **------>
>   Getting error here**

```
    let projectedPlaneCenter = self.sceneView.projectPoint(currentPosition)
    zVal = Double(projectedPlaneCenter.z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `*` is not defined for the operands `SCNVector3` and `Double`.

I am guessing that by `someVector * 0.1`, you mean multiplying each component of the vector by 0.1?

In that case, you could define your own `*` operator:

```
// put this in the global scope
func *(lhs: SCNVector3, rhs: Double) -> SCNVector3 {
    return SCNVector3(lhs.x * CGFloat(rhs), lhs.y * CGFloat(rhs), lhs.z * CGFloat(rhs))
}

// usage
SCNVector3(1, 2, 3) * 0.1 // (0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop this into your project, and it should work.

```
    public static func * (lhs: SCNVector3, rhs: Double) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(lhs.x * .init(rhs), lhs.y * .init(rhs), lhs.z * .init(rhs))
    }

    public static func * (lhs: Double, rhs: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        return rhs * lhs
    }
}
```